# WPF combobox value preselection doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

currently I'm working on an user interface to get values in order to process them for automation. Therefore I created a UserControl with the following XAML-Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DATEVswv_PackageCreator.SetPackageParameters"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DATEVswv_PackageCreator"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="900">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="89*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="45*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/> [...]
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Label Name="lbl_header" Content="Abschnitt 1: Paketdaten erfassen"  FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="grid_manufacturer">
            <Label Name="lbl_step1" Content="Schritt 1: Hersteller auswählen" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <ComboBox 
                x:Name="cbx_manufacturer" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="0,18,0,10" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                SelectionChanged="cbx_manufacturer_SelectionChanged" 
                IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
                IsEditable="True"
                />
        </Grid>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code-behind for this UserControl is:

```
public partial class SetPackageParameters : UserControl
{
    public SetPackageParameters()
    {
        dr.getmanufacturers();
        InitializeComponent();
        cbx_manufacturer.ItemsSource = DataReader.manufacturercollection;
    }
    DataReader dr = new DataReader();
    bool manufacturercreated = false;


    private void cbx_manufacturer_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (grid_tfsid.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || grid_packagetype.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || grid_language.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || grid_version.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || grid_product.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || grid_productowner.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || grid_packagecreator.Visibility == Visibility.Visible || grid_license.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            grid_tfsid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            grid_packagetype.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            grid_language.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            grid_version.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            grid_product.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            grid_productowner.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            grid_packagecreator.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            grid_license.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        try
        {
            if (cbx_manufacturer.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Neu" && DataReader.manufacturercollection.Contains(MainWindow.tempstring) == false)
            {
                manufacturercreated = true;
                AddValue add = new AddValue();
                add.ShowDialog();
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Vor der Bearbeitung hatte die manufacturercollection {0} Einträge.", DataReader.manufacturercollection.Count));
                DataReader.manufacturercollection.Add(MainWindow.tempstring);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} wurde der Collection manufacturercollection hinzugefügt. Die Collection hat jetzt {1} Einträge.", MainWindow.tempstring, DataReader.manufacturercollection.Count));
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Der ausgewählte Index wird auf {0} festgelegt.", DataReader.manufacturercollection.Count - 1));
                cbx_manufacturer.SelectedIndex = DataReader.manufacturercollection.Count - 1;
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Der ausgewählte Index wurde auf {0} festgelegt.", cbx_manufacturer.SelectedIndex));
            }
            else
            {
                if (manufacturercreated)
                {
                    cbx_manufacturer.SelectedIndex = DataReader.manufacturercollection.Count - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    MainWindow.tempstring = cbx_manufacturer.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }
                dr.getproducts(cbx_manufacturer.SelectedValue.ToString());
                grid_product.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                cbx_product.ItemsSource = DataReader.productcollection;
            }

        }
        catch
    }   { }
}
```

The AddValue class is a simple window that saves the entered string into the variable MainWindow.tempstring.

The ObservableCollection DataReade.manufacturercollection is filled in the class DataReader:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace DATEVswv_PackageCreator
{
    class DataReader
    {
        private string[] paths;
        public static List<string> packages = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> manufacturers = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> products = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> versions = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> languages = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> packagetypes = new List<string>();
        private static List<string> tfsids = new List<string>();
        public static ObservableCollection<string> manufacturercollection;
        public static ObservableCollection<string> productcollection;
        public static ObservableCollection<string> versioncollection;
        public static ObservableCollection<string> languagecollection;
        public static ObservableCollection<string> packagetypecollection;
        public static ObservableCollection<string> tfsidcollection;

        private void getfoldernames(string path)
        {
            paths = Directory.GetDirectories(path);


        }
        private void getfoldernames(string path, string pattern)
        {
            pattern = "*" + pattern + "*";
            paths = Directory.GetDirectories(path, pattern);
        }
        public void cleanpaths()
        {
            getfoldernames(Params.path);
            packages.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
            {
                paths[i] = paths[i].Remove(0, Params.path.Length + 1);
                if (paths[i].StartsWith("_") == false)
                {
                    packages.Add(paths[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        public List<string> cleanpaths(string pattern)
        {
            getfoldernames(Params.path, pattern);
            packages.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < paths.Length; i++)
            {
                paths[i] = paths[i].Remove(0, Params.path.Length + 1);
                if (paths[i].StartsWith("_") == false)
                {
                    packages.Add(paths[i]);
                }
            }
            return packages;
        }
        public void getmanufacturers()
        {
            cleanpaths();
            manufacturers.Clear();
            manufacturers.Add("Neu");
            foreach (string item in packages)
            {
                var temparray = item.Split('_');
                manufacturers.Add(temparray[0]);
            }
            manufacturers = manufacturers.Distinct().ToList();
            manufacturercollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(manufacturers);

        }
        public void getproducts(string manufacturer)
        {

            packages = cleanpaths(MainWindow.tempstring);

            products.Clear();
            products.Add("Neu");
            foreach (string item in packages)
            {
                var temparray = item.Split('_');
                if (temparray[0] == manufacturer && temparray != null)
                {
                    products.Add(temparray[1]);
                }
            }
            products = products.Distinct().ToList();
            productcollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(products);
        }
        public void getversions(string product)
        {
            packages = cleanpaths(MainWindow.tempstring);

            versions.Clear();
            versions.Add("Neu");
            foreach (string item in packages)
            {
                var temparray = item.Split('_');
                if (temparray[1] == product && temparray != null)
                {
                    versions.Add(temparray[2]);
                }
            }
            versions = versions.Distinct().ToList();
            versioncollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(versions);
        }
        public void getlanguages(string version)
        {
            packages = cleanpaths(MainWindow.tempstring);

            languages.Clear();
            languages.Add("Neu");
            foreach (string item in packages)
            {
                var temparray = item.Split('_');
                if (temparray[2] == version && temparray != null)
                {
                    languages.Add(temparray[3]);
                }
            }
            languages = languages.Distinct().ToList();
            languagecollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(languages);
        }
        public void getpackagetypes(string language)
        {
            packages = cleanpaths(MainWindow.tempstring);

            packagetypes.Clear();
            packagetypes.Add("Neu");
            foreach (string item in packages)
            {
                var temparray = item.Split('_');
                if (temparray[3] == language && temparray != null)
                {
                    packagetypes.Add(temparray[4]);
                }
            }
            packagetypes = packagetypes.Distinct().ToList();
            packagetypecollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(packagetypes);
        }
        public void gettfsids(string packagetype)
        {
            packages = cleanpaths(MainWindow.tempstring);

            tfsids.Clear();
            tfsids.Add("Neu");
            foreach (string item in packages)
            {
                var temparray = item.Split('_');
                if (temparray[4] == packagetype && temparray != null)
                {
                    tfsids.Add(temparray[5]);
                }
            }
            tfsids = tfsids.Distinct().ToList();
            tfsidcollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(tfsids);
        }

    }
}
```

The Params-class only gets the configuration values from a xml-file and puts them into static variables.

The problem: When I select the item "Neu" to create a new item it properly adds that string to the `DataReader.manufacturercollection` and says that the value was selected. But the value in the combobox is still "Neu". The error is the same for all the other collections that are created in class DataReader.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `cbx_manufacturer.SelectedItem = DataReader.manufacturercollection.Last();`. For your next WPF project, I urge you to learn MVVM and use databinding. There's a bit of a learning curve, but all of this code could be much simpler and easier to work with.

Comment: Are you typing "Neu" in the ComboBox to trigger your SelectionChanged? Because you have editing enabled, what is happening is it is autocompleting with "Neu" item when you hit N, so changing selected item to "Neu", which creates the new item and changing selected item. However the editing textbox still is showing the "Neu" item that was first selected. My advice if you kept this code would be to turn off IsEditable so this doesn't happen. But I would strongly suggest learning MVVM as Ed suggested first, and implementing the selection via a binding.

Comment: Thank you EdPlunkett for that approach. But unfortunately it still isn't working... @Rachel: I only need to type N and then the window opens directly. So you could say that it's autocompleting. Yes, disabling "IsEditable" really helps. Is there any other possibility to directly search in that list?

Comment: @Dominik The AutoComplete is fine, the problem is the TextBox used for editing. Textboxes don't persist their value until focus is lost by default, so it will still display "Neu" even though the selected item is something different. You might be able to change that behavior by overwriting the template, however in this case I'd recommend just disabling editing.